# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() fails for some characters

Tags: c#, string, unicode, character-encoding, character-entities

See this code:

```
namespace TestHtmlDecode
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using System.Web;

    [TestClass]
    public class TestHtmlDecode
    {
        private string Convert(string input)
        {
            return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestLeftBrace()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("{", Convert("&lbrace;"));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestGreaterThan()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(">", Convert("&gt;"));
        }
    }
}
```

`TestGreaterThan` passes, but `TestLeftBrace` fails (`Convert` returns `&lbrace;`). Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are two things going on here.

1. `&lbrace` is a { and not [ (http://jsfiddle.net/B7AAh/1/)
2. It doesn't look like `&lbrace` is included in the list of of known items. Source code is here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebUtility.cs which refers to the list of entities found here http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html

Comment: 1. Oops that was a mistake :) 2. Do you know what I can use to replace `HtmlDecode()`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of anything.   Would probably be pretty straightforward to wrap a call to to it and then have a secondary list though?  Want to start a new project :) ?